View content that was added during the merge and comes from neither parent
During a merge with git 2.42.0.windows.2 and the Bash console, I had to manually perform some modifications to get it to compile, which I then committed along with the modifications due to the merge itself. Those modifications therefore can be traced to neither parent of the merge commit, but rather are new from the merge commit onwards. I want to talk about those changes with someone else. Can I get git to list them, and only them, under a diff format? If yes, how?
Example in my git playground :
I have file2 with "Original file2 content." I create two branches, A and B, that both concurrently modify file2 (the fact that the modification is concurrent, or even in the same file, is not relevant. I just did it this way in this example). Here is what the file looks like after merging and before committing the merge :

Bear with me here. Branch B is revision B here (as KDiff3 names it) and branch A is revision C. The lines with "m" Are manual modifications I made.
I want a git command that outputs something like :
file2: line 6 +Extra content to make the merge between A and B work.
Neither git diff -c nor git diff --cc nor git diff --cc --combined-all-paths nor git diff-tree -c -p seem to produce the result I want.

Try git show.

Care to expand ?

IMO git show, git show @, git show HEAD, git show <commit-ID> (where  HEAD or <commit-ID> are merge commits) are closest to what you want.
